# Git Checkout conflicts when i want to switch to another branch

Tags: python, eclipse, git

I have problem with git. When I want to switch to another branch from Eclipse it shows me [this dialog](http://snag.gy/dLf7Q.jpg).

and in src folder, i have gitignore file with these values

```
**/\__pycache__/

**/*.pyc
```

When I go to source location of these files from screenshot, I delete them, but same thing happens.

Comment: Linked screenshot properly and removeirrelevant gitlab references

Answer (score 0):

Just because a file is matched by `.gitignore` won't ignore it if it is somehow added to git already (Incidentally, just `*.pyc` is all you need in `.gitignore`).

This is why I do not trust git GUIs in general, or any attempt to "automatically add all changes".

You need to checkout each branch and `git rm` the file and commit that. Only if the file is *not* in the tree for the current branch do you need to manually delete it from the filesystem if it's present on a different branch. Additionally, you may need to make sure that your IDE isn't automatically regenerating the .pyc files without you requesting to run or import the program.

Alternatively, you could use `git filter-branch` to actually remove the files from history. This would require a force push and is significantly more complicated.